# How can I create dynamically an Add Forms in Django with Formsets and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django-forms

I'am writting a application to allow users in a port to declare all goods that arrived in boat.The MANIFESTE model is containing all information related to boat and MANIFESTEITEMS model contains all the goods that have to manifested. Two importators may have the same product name in the same boat with or not the same quantity.All the goods that come in the same boat are using the same manifeste id.
So, if the form is full and still we have items remain to be added in the current manifeste id, we have to click on a button to display more empty manifesteItems fields. If there is no more items, we submit the form to save the manifeste and manifesteItems by clicking on the save button.
Here are my two models

```
class MANIFESTE(models.Model):
    provenance = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    nom_du_navire = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    numero_du_voyage = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    date_arrive = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_creation',)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'MANIFESTE {}'.format(self.id)
    # valide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    importator = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)


class MANIFESTEITEMS(models.Model):
        manifest = models.ForeignKey(MANIFESTE, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='manifeste_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
        # price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
        unite_de_mesure = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, choices=product_unit)
        chargeur = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
        destinataire = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
        telephone = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
```

The idea is, in the same form to be able to display dinamically when the user clicks on an add item button more manifesteitems fields before submitting the form. When he/she click on the save button, all the items informations bellonging to the same manifeste id should be sent to the database.
With views function I'm able to save one goods.

```
def create_manifest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        manifeste_form = ManifesteCreateForm(request.POST)
        formset = ManifesteItemFormset(request.POST)

        if manifeste_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            manifeste = manifeste_form.save()
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.manifest = manifeste
                instance.save()
            return redirect('manifeste_list')
    else:
        manifeste_form = ManifesteCreateForm()
        formset = ManifesteItemFormset()

    context = {
        'manifeste_form': manifeste_form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'MANIFESTE/create_manifest.html', context)
```

When I click on the Ajouter un article button, I'm not getting more fields appear on the form in order to be able to add more MANIFESTEITEMS fieLds. It seems that the JS code does not working properly.
How can I

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}  
    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="content container-fluid">
            <!-- Page Header -->
            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3 class="page-title"></h3>
                        <ul class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="admin-dashboard.html">Tableau de bord</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Manifeste</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Page Header -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card mb-0">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'MANIFESTE:create_manifest' %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                
                                <!-- Display Manifeste fields -->
                                {{ manifeste_form.as_p }}
                                
                                <!-- Display ManifesteItem fields -->
                                {{ formset.management_form }}
                                <div id="formset-container">
                                    {% for form in formset %}
                                        <div class="formset-row">
                                            {{ form.as_p }}
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                                
                                <!-- Add ManifesteItem button -->
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="add-manifeste-item">Ajouter un article</button>
                                
                                <!-- Save button -->
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Page Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Page Wrapper -->
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize formset
        var formsetPrefix = '{{ formset.prefix }}';
        var formsetTotalForms = {{ formset.total_form_count }};
        var emptyFormsetRow = $('#formset-empty-row').html();

        function updateFormsetRowIndexes() {
            // Update formset row indexes
            $('#formset-container .formset-row').each(function (index) {
                $(this).find('input, select').each(function () {
                    var oldName = $(this).attr('name');
                    var newName = oldName.replace(/form-[0-9]+/, 'form-' + index);
                    $(this).attr('name', newName);

                    var oldId = $(this).attr('id');
                    var newId = oldId.replace(/form-[0-9]+/, 'form-' + index);
                    $(this).attr('id', newId);
                });
            });
        }

        function addFormsetRow() {
            var newRow = emptyFormsetRow.replace(/__prefix__/g, formsetTotalForms);
            $('#formset-container').append(newRow);
            formsetTotalForms++;
            updateFormsetRowIndexes();
        }

        // Add formset row when the button is clicked
        $(document).on('click', '#add-formset-row', function () {
            addFormsetRow();
        });

        // Add formset rows for existing forms
        for (var i = 0; i < formsetTotalForms; i++) {
            addFormsetRow();
        }
    });
</script>


{% endblock scripts %}
```

How can I do it?